# Get just object values

Tags: python

I have this array of objects

`[{'brand_id': 607, 'store_id': 4, 'refIdInMyStore': '3108'}, {'brand_id': 608, 'store_id': 4, 'refIdInMyStore': '3109'}]`

How can i transform into

`[[607,4,3108], [608,4,3109]]`

Comment: `[[d['brand_id'], d['store_id'], int(d['refIdInMyStore'])] for d in objects]`?

Answer (score 1):

something like that (just grab the `values()`). **Note** that the values are passed to a `list` in order to convert them from dict values to a list. (see below **@**)

```
data = [{'brand_id': 607, 'store_id': 4, 'refIdInMyStore': '3108'}, {'brand_id': 608, 'store_id': 4, 'refIdInMyStore': '3109'}]
values = [list(e.values()) for e in data]
print(values)
```

output

```
[[607, 4, '3108'], [608, 4, '3109']]
```

dict values: (**@**)

```
data = [{'brand_id': 607, 'store_id': 4, 'refIdInMyStore': '3108'}, {'brand_id': 608, 'store_id': 4, 'refIdInMyStore': '3109'}]
print((data[0].values()))
```

output

```
dict_values([607, 4, '3108'])
```